# Composite differents parts of render. (Creating Masks)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, masking, compositing-nodes

Can I have different compositor nodes for different parts of my render? I presume the way to do it would be using masks but I just cant figure out how to create/make them work.

Half of my render is blue and the other half is orange, so I would like to have different color balances and stuff for each side.

So my question is: How can I do that? And if using masks, how to I create a mask of my render and them use it on the compositor?

Thanks! =) (sorry if the question was confusing)

Comment: Hi :). Yes, you can limit compositor nodes using a mask (any BW image/gradient will do). But please add an example of your render and preferred mask type :)

Comment: So that's a preview of my render and the red circles would be the two masks I would like to composite individually. https://imgur.com/a/lKr6qtm

Comment: Ok so I found out how to create masks, now how can I composite them alone? Like, have a different color balance node for each mask?

Comment: Ok so I was able to figure out how to use the color balance, I just connect my mask node to the "Fac", but how about other nodes? Like "Lens Distortion" and "Glare" for example.

Comment: Hi :). Simply use a Mix node, with your mask plugged into *fac*. You can use it with any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Jachym commented here is an example:

here with part glare: (as you wanted, solution via mix node and mask image)

[image]

without glare: (i just muted the glare node)

[image]

with full glare: (glare connected to viewer instead mix node to viewer)

[image]